# Parsing nested XML

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, serialization, linq-to-xml

It seems like a very basic task and I am wondering if I am using the wrong search terms since I am not finding a solution to this...

I have a very simple, nested XML:

```
<books>
    <book>
        <author>Douglas Adams</author>
        <title>The Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy</title>
        <price>42</price>
    </book>
</books>
```

I am the Web API to get the XMl content returned into a stream, ending with the above pasted content in the variable `xmlStream`:

```
var xmlStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

xmlDocument.Load(xmlStream);

Console.WriteLine("Title:");
// Do something to get the value of 'title'
Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument.someTraversion...);
```

Since I haven't worked with XML much I am not quiet sure how to traverse into the **title attribute**.

I read about [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) and am trying to understand how to [navigate the DOM tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx#Navigate). I am afraid I don't get the terminology `nodes`, `child`. Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: I don't mind being downvoted but would appreciate a comment on what to improve in my question :-)

Comment: As for terminology, a "Child" would be an element that is inside another element.  In this case, `Author` is a child of `Book`, which is a  child of `Books`.  From `Books` point of view, `Author` is not a child, but an ancestor.  A "node" is any syntactic part of the XML, the entire document is a node, a single element is a node, an attribute is a node, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much @BradleyUffner! This makes more sense now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LINQ of XML`

```
XElement document = null;
using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
   document = XElement.Load(stream);
}

foreach(var book in document.Descendants("book"))
{
    var title = book.Element("title").Value;
    // use title
}
```

Notice that using `ReadAsStreamAsync().Result` can possibly throw a deadlock error - use "correct" await approach

```
var result = await ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Fabio! I am getting the following error message: `XmlElement` does not contain a defintion for 'Load'

Comment: `XDocument` and `XElement` are supposed to be `XmlDocument` and `XmlElement` right?

Comment: @jrn , no. XDocument is class from System.Xml.Linq.

Comment: Got it!
All I had to change was `XDocument document = null;` into `XElement document = null;`. Thanks a lot for your help @Fabio! :-)

Comment: Also, thank you very much for pointing out the possible deadlock error! I changed my code accordingly! Appreciate it :-)